# Regex: pattern contains 0 or more special characters

Tags: php, regex

this syntax returns an array with a word key.

```
(?<item>\w+)
```

ex. $array['item']

I want the return value in this form *but* I want to search for a word that may or may not contain parentheses (with values in between).

"hello"
or
"hello(some text and line breaks)"

What is the syntax for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\w+(?:\([^)]*\))?
```

will match words that can optionally be directly followed by a parenthesized text. Nested parentheses are not allowed.

```
\w+    # Match alnum characters
(?:    # Match the following (non-capturing) group:
 \(    # literal (
 [^)]* # any number of characters except )
 \)    # literal )
)?     # End of group; make it optional
```

Comment: I believe that `(?:` actually denotes a *non-capturing* group, rather than an optional one.  The optionality is determined solely from the `?` at the **end**; the initial `?:` simply causes the regex engine not to make this group available as a backreference (which is more efficient when you're not going to refer to it as such).  One could omit this character pair without changing the boolean matching behaviour of the regex.

Comment: @Andrzey: I know; I just mentioned it there to show that all that follows will be optional (which you would otherwise only find out at the end). I admit it is misleading. Will clarify.

Answer (score 0):

```
hello(\(\))?
```

or if your regex engine defaults parentheses to normal character

```
hello\(()\)?
```

Comment: This just matches `hello` or `hello()` but nothing else. There is nothing in the regex to account for the fact that there might be something between the parentheses.

Comment: i answered this question and afterwards he editted his question to allow for text between the parentheses